# Python removing specific duplicates from a list

Tags: python

I want to remove specific duplicates from a list. With Perl I would do the task with this code:

```
my @list = ( 'a1', 'a1', 'b1', 'b1' );

my %seen;
@list = grep( !/a\d/ || !$seen{ $_ }++, @list );
```

and the wanted result would be this:

```
@list = ( 'a1', 'b1', 'b1' );
```

How could I do this in Python 3 using regular expression and list comprehension. Thanks.

Comment: I don't speak perl. Does that code remove duplicates when the duplicates match the regex `/a\d/` but not otherwise?

Comment: Yes. The code removes only the duplicates that match the regex /a\d/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) :

```
>>> list(chain(*[[i[0]] if 'a1' in i else i for i in [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l))]]))
['a1', 'b1', 'b1']
```

and if you just want to use `regex` you can concatenate the elements the n use `re.sub` , but note that it works for this special case  ! that `,` is the delimiter ! :

```
>>> l =['a1', 'a1', 'b1', 'b1']
>>> re.sub(r'(a1,)+','a1,',','.join(sorted(l))).split(',')
['a1', 'b1', 'b1']
```

Comment: I'm not convinced you understood what the OP meant by "using regex". In any case, your regex solution is very brittle (what if there is a comma *inside* one or more of the elements?) and is not guaranteed to retain the original sequence of the elements, which might be important.

Comment: @JohnY yep , i just add it for this case , but anyway i need to add this point to answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from functools import reduce  # this import is not needed in python 2.*

l = ['a1', 'a1', 'b1', 'b1']

print reduce(lambda acc, el: acc if re.match(r'a\d', el) and el in acc else acc + [el], l, [])
```

Sorry, this is solution without list comprehensions. Is it strictly required?

Comment: No. List comprehension is not strictly required. I was looking for a one line solution and yours fits perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, using `list(set(stuff))` to generate a `list` of unique things from `stuff` (since `set`s automatically deduplicate things):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: l = ["a1", "a1", "b1", "b1"]

In [3]: items_to_dedupe = [x for x in l if re.match(r"a\d", x)]

In [4]: leave_alone = [x for x in l if x not in items_to_dedupe]

In [5]: list(set(items_to_dedupe)) + leave_alone
Out[5]: ['a1', 'b1', 'b1']
```