# How can I remove specific duplicates from a list, rather than remove all duplicates indiscriminately?

Tags: python

In a python script, I need to assess whether a string contains duplicates of a specific character (e.g., "f") and, if so, remove all but the first instance of that character. Other characters in the string may also have duplicates, but the script should not remove any duplicates other than those of the specified character.

This is what I've got so far. The script runs, but it is not accomplishing the desired task. I modified the reduce() line from the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245291/python-removing-specific-duplicates-from-a-list), but it's a little more complex than what I've learned at this point, so it's difficult for me to tell what part of this is wrong.

```
import re
from functools import reduce
string = "100 ffeet"
dups = ["f", "t"]
for char in dups:
    if string.count(char) > 1:
        lst = list(string)
        reduce(lambda acc, el: acc if re.match(char, el) and el in acc else acc + [el], lst, [])
string = "".join(lst)
```

Comment: This use of `functools.reduce` is producing a is a needlessly inefficient algorithm (quadratic time) when using a naive for loop to build up the list would give you a linear time algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a function that receives a string `s` and a character `c` as parameters, and returns a new string where all but the first occurrence of `c` in `s` are removed.

We'll be making use of the following functions from Python std lib:

- [`str.find(sub)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find): Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found.
- [`str.replace(old, new)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace): Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.

The idea is straightforward:

1. Find the first index of `c` in `s`

   1. If none is found, return `s`
2. Make a substring of `s` starting from the next character after `c`
3. Remove all occurrences of `c` in the substring
4. Concatenate the first part of `s` with the updated substring
5. Return the final string

In Python:

```py
def remove_all_but_first(s, c):
    i = s.find(c)

    if i == -1:
        return s

    i += 1

    return s[:i] + s[i:].replace(c, '')
```

Now you can use this function to remove all the characters you want.

```py
def main():
    s = '100 ffffffffeet'
    dups = ['f', 't', 'x']

    print('Before:', s)

    for c in dups:
        s = remove_all_but_first(s, c)

    print('After:', s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Amazing! That is exactly what I had in mind but wasn't able to realize. And extra thanks for the thoughtful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that you could do it

```
string = "100 ffeet"
dups = ["f", "t"]
seen = []

for s in range(len(string)-1,0,-1):

    if string[s] in dups and string[s] in seen:
        string = string[:s] + '' + string[s+1:]

    elif string[s] in dups:
        seen.append(string[s])

print(string)
```